# Alternative to component using props for state

Tags: reactjs

I have a bottom level component that is used to display success/ error messaging in my application. Currently it is using props for it's state, which has worked up until this point. The problem I'm facing is when returned in a certain component the state isn't changing once the component is rendered once. I.E. The message will show up once correctly and then it doesn't show up again because the state stays set to false.

Here is the function that renders the component. This function sits in the parent component.

```
renderSnackBar(type, message) {

    console.log('snackbar function invoked');

    return <Snackbar open={true} type={type} message={message} />
  }
```

Here is the child component

```
class MySnackbar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    open: this.props.open,
  };
}

  handleClose = (event, reason) => {
    if (reason === 'clickaway') {
      return;
    }

    this.setState({ open: false });
  };

  render() {

    const { type, message } = this.props

    let icon = <SuccessIcon color={colors.lightBlue} />
    let color = colors.lightBlue
    console.log('state', this.state, 'props', this.props);

    switch (type) {
      case 'Error':
        icon = <ErrorIcon color={colors.red} />
        color = colors.red
        break;
      case 'Success':
        icon = <SuccessIcon color={colors.lightBlue} />
        color = colors.lightBlue
        break;
      case 'Warning':
        icon = <WarningIcon color={colors.orange} />
        color = colors.orange
        break;
      case 'Info':
        icon = <InfoIcon color={colors.lightBlue} />
        color = colors.lightBlue
        break;
      default:
        icon = <SuccessIcon color={colors.lightBlue} />
        color = colors.lightBlue
        break;
    }

    return (
      <Snackbar
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: 'bottom',
          horizontal: 'left',
        }}
        open={this.state.open}
        autoHideDuration={6000}
        onClose={this.handleClose}
        message={
          <div style={{ padding: '12px 24px', borderLeft: '5px solid '+color, borderRadius: '4px'}}>
            {icon}
            <div style={{ display: 'inline-block', verticalAlign: 'middle', maxWidth: '400px' }}>
              <Typography variant='body1' style={{ fontFamily: 'Montserrat-SemiBold', fontSize: '12px' }}>{type}</Typography>
              <Typography variant='body1' style={{ fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Medium', fontSize: '10px', color: colors.darkGray }} noWrap>{message}</Typography>
            </div>
          </div>
        }
        action={[
          <IconButton
            key="close"
            aria-label="Close"
            color={colors.darkGray}
            onClick={this.handleClose}
          >
            <CloseIcon />
          </IconButton>,
        ]}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default MySnackbar;
```

From what I gather using props to initialize state is an antipattern. How can I use this component without using props as state?

Comment: what is the event to open a snackbar?

Comment: @JosephD.  I'm using expressions in the parent components render method. Specifically in the return at the bottom of my grid. `{ error && this.renderSnackBar('Error', error) }
        { success && this.renderSnackBar('Success', success ) }

      </Grid>`

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the problem you have right now is caused by the fact that you have 2 sources of truth (1 from props, and 1 from state) for determining whether your SnackBar should `open` or not.

So, what we want to do is to make it so that there is only 1 source of truth for your component. Usually, we want to keep the `props` as the source of truth, not the `state`.

What we could do is to add a prop called `onClose` to your SnackBar, and have the SnackBar invoke the function inside `handleClose`. `onClose` should change the `open` value from the parent component, so the value passed down to SnackBar is updated accordingly. Now, the SnackBar does not have to have its own state anymore, it can just rely on the props passed to it. [Here is an example implementation on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-tu-l8bhc?fontsize=14).

Comment: Unfortunately the application would require a ton of reformatting to do this fix as I'd have to add this state to all of my top level containers and drill it down as props. I'm looking for a fix that I can implement with the current architecture I have.

Comment: If that is the case, I would recommend putting the `open` value into a Context. Then, Snackbar would only need to read the `open` value from the context, and `handleClose` (in SnackBar itself) would just set the `open` value in the context to `false`. So now you are not depending on either `state` or `props`, but only on `Context`. The idea is the same, make it so you only have 1 source of truth. But with Context, you don't need to pass the value as props down so many levels.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by context? Do you mean use the context API?

Comment: Yes, I am referring to the Context API.

Comment: @larryburns this refactoring is very necessary, or else even if you are able to fix this current issue, you're just creating more technical debt for this project. Besides using Context API (which is easier to implement in this case), the other option would be MobX or Redux, or just pass the props all the way down manually.

Comment: Yeah I've taken over this project and I'm aware I'll have to refactor the code. I'm just looking for a bandaid for now essentially so I can push this update.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you receive the open prop that is not the same as state you can change state with [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops)

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps({open}, state) {
  if (open !==state.open) {
    //use open from props
    return {
      ...state,
      open
    };
  }  
  // Return null to indicate no change to state.
  return null;
}
```

You may now have a component that doesn't close anymore depending on how you call renderSnackbar, if that's the case then I need to know more on how you call the renderSnackbar function.